# Why the first letter gets matched in regex

Tags: regex

**UPDATE: actually if I want to match "-" I have to use - when there is something after -**

All:

Why in this example:

```
var a = "Pencil_sharper.pdf"
a.split(/[. -_]+/g)
(4) ["", "encil", "sharper", "pdf"]
```

I expected

```
["Pencil", "sharper", "pdf"]
```

Comment: Use `a.split(/[. _-]+/g)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I get it.